# ActiveMQ consumer slows down after few days

Tags: performance, activemq-classic, kahadb

We are an `ActiveMQ` setup with all default settings. Its broker url is like `failover:(tcp://host1,tcp://host2,tcp://host3)?randomize=false`

We have 2 message Queues where producer publishes persistent messages.

Messages generally have a steady flow but when markets open then there is burst of messages for almost 2 hours. This setup works fine for 2-3 days and then consumer slows down in processing messages and we see queue build ups.

Consumer performs following steps:

1. Transform message.
2. Process it
3. Add to cache and DB.

`Prefetch size` is 1000.

Following are some of the observations:

1. Consumer processing doesn't seem to be the issue else it would have always slowed down.
2. Looks like ActiveMQ broker slows down in processing but i dont have evidence
3. We have observed that out of 3 hosts only host 1 and 2 process majority of messages.

Any ideas on how to explain this slowness?

EDIT:

Analysed this further and found that `Kahadb` store [`Persistent` messages are stored in `Kahadb` in broker] reaches 100% storage when consumer slows down.
I can understand that producer is blocked when storage reaches 100% but why would consumer slow down? Is it because `Kahadb` may slow down during this time and extracting messages equivalent to prefetch size takes more?

Comment: What is observed to be slow? What's the CPU load on each host? What happens after rebooting consumer / brokers? Do you have the possibility to profile? Can you reproduce the issue on other machines?

Comment: Message consumption is observed to be slow. During slowness, CPU load doesn't shoot up. If we reboot consumer, slowness goes away [we haven't rebooted broker]. Issue is reproducible on QA as well as Prod machines.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the consumer. Why do you suspect the broker? Isn't it possible that the consumer slows down over time? Maybe locking issues? Or OutOfMemoryError? Any not persistent state that could have influence? Is it possible that the cache slows down for example?

Comment: Consumer has fixed set of steps to do, which remain constant throughout. It seems reconnection to broker solves the issue. We have checked and sufficient memory is available